# Application: Should I attach a resumé, cover letter AND write an additional application in the email?

Tags: resume, internship, applications, cover-letter, ireland

I am currently trying to find a summer job in Dublin in the field of graphic design or web design.

I already encountered that specific problem when applying in Austria, but I am completely unsure how this is handled in Ireland.

I have written my resumé containing my education, work experience and skills. Now my next step would be to write a cover letter. But I also need an application "letter" which is the body of my email sent to the company.

What's the difference between the email and the cover letter? Should I make both of these or should I write everything in the cover letter and only include 2 - 3 sentences in the email? If I should write two letters, should both be customized to the company I am applying to or just the email. (Because my Resumé isn't customed, as it just includes general information, I would include in the cover letter only general information too).

PS: The position I am applying for is a speculative application for a 2-month-job

PPS: I have my resumé and my cover letter both designed in my own corporate design. Would it be better then to attach both as a pdf and just write a short text in the mail?

Answer (score 4):

I personally just use the email as a quick message as I don't want the email program they use to butcher my cover letter formatting.

In my email, I say something like

> Hello,
>
> My application for #job title here# is attached.
>
> Thank you for taking the time to consider my application.
>
> Seraphina

One good trick my former boss showed me was to change the email from HTML to plain text then back again to HTML.  That drops all special formatting and makes it look clean and professional.

Also, use a proper email.  Preferably one with your name in it.  Not your gamer handle or something silly.  Gmail is free, make a professional sounding email address.

Comment: Seraphina!  awesome  :)

Answer (score 1):

The 'application letter' IS the cover letter.  Different terminology, same concept.  And don't even think of not customizing that for every job application, you need to highlight how suitable you are for this particular job in every single one.

I usually send the cover letter as the email, and only attach the resume.  People need to be able to see quickly what you're talking about.  And be sure to use an informative subject too 'applying for --- position', and to name your resume something which can be found quickly 'resume_name.pdf'..

Comment: Thanks. Yes, one of the two would have been customized, if I had to send two different, then the mail would have been customized. Customizing the pdf is a little bit too much effort for applying at over 50 companies xD

Comment: @Seraphina You should customize all of them.  And if any respond, that's when you start studying the company very closely.  Your resume and cover letter should be customized for every job.

Comment: Ideally I agree with Trevor, customizing the resume for every job is a help too.  But OP if what's holding you back is that you have trouble generating pdfs you should address that directly, because it should be a piece of cake.  I like pdfCreator, which acts like a printer, for instance.